# Jolt Spec for Json that may or may not have Array

Tags: json, jolt

Any help is greatly Appreciated.

I Have input JSON that can have Phone in array or it can be blank or it can be missing.

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "abc",
    "Phone": [
      {
        "office-1": "123",
        "home-1": "989"
      },
      {
        "office-1": "456",
        "home-1": "999"
      }
    ],
    "Email": "abc@123.com"
  },
  {
    "Name": "efg",
    "Phone": [],
    "Email": "efg@123.com"
  },
  {
    "Name": "xyz",
    "Email": "xyz@123.com"
  }
]
```

My Jolt is already able to convert the Phone number array, but it is not working if the label Phone is missing in JSON input.

Expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "abc",
    "office-1": "123",
    "home-1": "989",
    "Email": "abc@123.com"
  },
  {
    "Name": "abc",
    "office-1": "456",
    "home-1": "999",
    "Email": "abc@123.com"
  },
  {
    "Name": "efg",
    "Email": "efg@123.com"
  },
  {
    "Name": "xyz",
    "Email": "xyz@123.com"
  }
]
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can walk through the objects after separating the stuff under Phone node and the others such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Phone": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3.&1.&",
            "@(2,Name)": "&3.&1.Name",
            "@(2,Email)": "&3.&1.Email"
          }
        },
        "*": "&1.&1.&" // "else" case
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // get rid of duplicated values of some attributes
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Barbaros. If I changed the order of JSON input extra json object is created for array element. Please suggest what can de done for it.

Answer (score 0):

[new sample of data where I have kept non array data in between array data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdU0i.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).